# Searching for an author with unpublished fantasy writing for my mobile game

Tags: fiction, publishing, copyright, legal, world-building

I would be extremely grateful for any advice on how to search for or reach an agreement with an author. I'm a solo indie game developer, unreleased. My game is a fantasy random gacha hero collector. Multiplayer is 1v1 but each player controls 5 characters. Combat is styled after mmo arenas and moba. Solo gameplay consists of relatively linear paths within 3d scenes, no open world. Storyline is not intended to significantly impact gameplay. I am looking for an author that will allow me to world build upon their writing. I'm poor and a hobbyist but I'm very interested in the rights to unpublished novels or web series.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is looks like a job advertisement.

Comment: Could be a question for Freelancing.SE.